# Twitter API Auth

Tags: perl, curl, twitter, basic-authentication

I would like to get\post some twitter data without creating application(only by user_name\mail and password of twitter account). How can i do this? is it possible? I know this was possible around 2 years ago. But i dont know, what happens now. When do i try using Net::Twitter::Lite(perl module for this) with Basic Auth, this always return 400 or 403 return code.
Code example:

```
my $nt = Net::Twitter::Lite->new(
    username => "xxxx",
    password => "xxxx",
    legacy_lists_api => 0,   
);
my $result = eval { $nt->update('Hello, world!') };
```

$result is always empty.
May be i am doing something wrong? Or may be Twitter has blocked this opportunity to get their data.

Comment: Twitter basic auth was deprecated in 2010. See my answer for how to use key-based auth.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Twitter recently updated their API to require ssl, so pass the following to your `Net::Twitter` object:

```
ssl => 1
```

On top of this, you have to use API 1.1 key-based login rather than the old username/password login which is deprecated. I know you said you want to use username/password, but Twitter [deprecated Basic Auth in 2010 in favor of application keys](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-api-announce/wD-isa6Q0qk) due to security issues with having third parties handle & store login details.

Head over to [Twitter's developer portal](http://dev.twitter.com), log in and generate a set of (read/write) keys. You should end up with something like this (taken directly from my [FillyRT](https://github.com/Suhosin/FillyRT/blob/master/main.pl) codebase) - may be a little different for `Net::Twitter::Lite`, I haven't used it:

```
my $nt = Net::Twitter->new(
    traits              => [qw/API::RESTv1_1/],
    consumer_key        => $consumer_key,
    consumer_secret     => $consumer_secret,
    access_token        => $token,
    access_token_secret => $token_secret,
    ssl                 => 1
);
```

From here, you should be able to call your `update` function:

```
$nt->update('Hello world');
```

Comment: So....Thank you! Could you answer me on following questions: 1) consumer (key/secret) is a application part? 2) is token (key\secret) a user part? 3) May I combine different consumers and tokens? 4) May I generate token without generating consumer?

Comment: @gavrmike 1). API key & API secret (consumer) are specific to the application.

Comment: @gavrmike 2). Token key/secret are specific to the application, user and access level to be granted (read, read/write or read/write/DM).

Comment: 3). You can generate tokens for many users for your application, but those tokens won't work with other applications.

Comment: 4). No, you have to use the consumer keys to generate an access token. This is because the access token is unique to the user, application & privilege level combination.

Comment: Thanks for all! But I have another one question(for setting things straight): Do i use APIv1.1 without application? May be it will be generating tokens/consumers or something else, but it should not be creating application. PS I have understood that authentification by user/password is deprecated. But not all fell into place in my brain:)

Comment: @gavrmike You can use Oauth to generate a token but you'll still need to create an application.

Comment: You need to go here: https://apps.twitter.com/ - create an application and generate a token, to get those 4 fields. This will be specific to your app and user account (and rights created). Process of doing so is outlined here: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/application-owner-access-tokens